# Getting a typename given the typename of a pointer to it in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, typename

Consider the following code:

```
class c {
  //...
};

template <typename T>
void f(T k)
{
    auto item = new T;
    //...
}
```

We declare a class `c` and a template function `f` that creates a new object type `T`.

I want to change this function `f` so the template parameter can be a **pointer type**, it will be used as follows:

```
auto ptr = new c;
f<c*>(ptr);
```

Now, the problem comes when I try to create a new item `auto item = new T;`, because now `T` is now the typename of a *pointer to `c`*.

I know `T` will always be a pointer to something, **how can I get the typename  being pointed to by `T`?** I want to do something like:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T k)
{
    // If T = int* -> Q = int
    typename ??????? Q;    // <<<<<<<<
    auto item = new Q;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
#include <type_traits>

using Q = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;
```